# Passing function to a function and varying length arguments

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I have a two functions:

```
first - takes 1 argument
secon - takes 2 arguments
```

Then I have third function that receives a function and a value as argument.

I am unable to figure out how to make the third function know that it is receiving one argument or two argument depending on which function is passed in 2nd argument???

**In the below example, when third is called it should return 2 on both calls at the end of code.

```js
let val = 12;

let val2 = 14
let toC = 14;

// checks if val === 12 | takes 1 argument
const first = num => num === 12 ?2 :0;

// checks if val === toC | takes 2 arguments
const second = (num, check) => num === check ?2 :0;

// third function that receives a function and a val as arguments
const third = (func, num) => {
  let temp = func(num);
  return temp;
}

// this one works
console.log(third(first, val));

// this doesn't
console.log(third(second, (val2, toC)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `third` function is there to just invoke the function provided as an argument and return the value. In this case, you can use the [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).

```js
let val = 12;

let val2 = 14
let toC = 14;

// checks if val === 12 | takes 1 argument
const first = num => num === 12 ? 2 :0;

// checks if val === toC | takes 2 arguments
const second = (num, check) => num === check ?2 :0;

const third = (func, ...args) => {
  let temp = func(...args);
  return temp;
}


console.log(third(first, val));

console.log(third(second, val2, toC));
```

Comment: Hahaha!! I knew it was something simple and obvious. Been faffing around with spread operators and arguments!! Thank you thank you!